# How to replace value with square brackets using sed?

Tags: sed, brackets

I need to replace variables with square brackets in a file:

```
a=0
foo[1]=0
foo[2]=0
```

I want to replace `foo[1]=0` to `foo[1]=2`.

To change the values `a` I use:

```
func_update_value () {
     field=$1
     newvalue=$2
     sed -i "s/^\($field=\).*/\1$newvalue/" file
}

field="a"
value="2"
func_update_value $field $value
```

but the same command does not work for `foo[x]`...

```
func_update_value () {
     field=$1
     newvalue=$2
     sed -i "s/^\($field=\).*/\1$newvalue/" file
}    
n=1
field="foo[$n]"
value="2"
func_update_value $field $value
```

What is the right syntax with `sed`?

The change is made by a function, is it possible to use single `sed` command for both cases?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I modified the question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[1]` is not (i.e. not necessarily) literal in the shell. Then it's not (i.e. certainly not) literal as a part of a regex pattern in `sed`.

I've checked your previous questions and I guess you're using Bash. The first part of my answer applies to many common shells, including Bash (zsh is the notable exception).

---

#### Possible problem in the shell

At first you assign values to variables:

```
n=1
field="foo[$n]"
value="2"
```

All this works as you would expect. The unquoted `1` is not special, it doesn't need to be quoted. The quoted `2` might or might not be quoted and it would make no difference. Double-quotes around `foo[$n]` make a difference; it's good they are there, this way `[` and `]` are nothing special and the content of the `field` variable is literally `foo[1]` for sure.

But then you have

```
func_update_value $field $value
```

where `$field` is not quoted. Just after parameter expansion the line is

```
func_update_value foo[1] 2
```

and then [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) against objects in your current directory (globbing) kicks in, especially:

> `[…]`
>   Matches any one of the enclosed characters.

This means if you had a file or a directory named `foo1`, the line would evaluate to

```
func_update_value foo1 2
```

It would be even worse if you set `n=125` and you had `foo1` and `foo5` (and/or `foo2`) in the directory. More than one file would match the `foo[125]` pattern and the final form of the line would be like

```
func_update_value foo1 foo5 2
```

which is definitely not what you want. You *probably* don't have anything named `foo1` in the current directory, so the pattern stays literal at this point and the line

```
func_update_value foo[1] 2
```

runs the `func_update_value` function with literal arguments `foo[1]` and `2`.

If your code doesn't fail at this point, it's only by chance of not having `foo1` in the directory, not because of proper coding. Proper coding includes [double-quoting all variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). There are few rare scenarios where you'd want not to quote, *if you know what you're doing*; this is not one of them.

Also note in the function itself there is `field=$1` where `$1` is not quoted. The problem with unquoted `$1` is the same as with unquoted `$field` earlier.

---

#### Problem in `sed`

Let's suppose your function properly got the literal `foo[1]` argument and its local `field` variable now contains the literal string `foo[1]` as it should.

The problem is `[1]` as a part of a regex pattern in `sed` is not literal. Like in the shell, it matches any one of the enclosed characters (except matching is against text, not filenames). `foo[125]` would match `foo1` or `foo2` or `foo5`. `foo[1]` matches `foo1` only.

To make `sed` match `[` and `]` literally, you need to escape them in the pattern. Instead of `field="foo[$n]"` you need

```
field="foo\[$n\]"
```

> is it possible to use single `sed` command for both cases?

Yes. Your current command is like `sed "s/^\($field=\).*/\1$newvalue/"` and it will work as long as you keep in mind the value of `$field` will be interpreted as a part of the pattern (so `[`, `.`, `\(`, `$` etc. are special) and the value of `$newvalue` will be interpreted as a part of the replacement (so e.g. `\1` is special). And there is the separator you chose (`/`) which mustn't occur in any of the two variables, or else it will break or change the syntax.

---

#### Final note

The second fix alone (adding backslashes before `[` and `]`) would even prevent the shell from expanding `[…]`, so it would accidentally "fix" the quoting issue in this particular case, for this particular value of the variable.

In general though you should apply both fixes. And you certainly should get used to quoting variables by default, this will save you time and frustration while debugging your future shell scripts. That's why my answer doesn't limit itself to the second fix.